# How to improve Haar Cascade accuracy in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, haar-classifier

I have collected 1000 positive(50*50) images and 1000 negative(50*50) images and trained Haar Cascade in OpenCV. I am trying to detect mobile phones.
code for training :

```
opencv_traincascade -data data -vec crop1.vec -bg mob_neg.txt -numPos 900 -numNeg 900 -numStages 15 -w 50 -h 50 bgcolor 255 -bgthresh 100
```

cascade is unable to detect mobile accurately (it is detecting mobile as well as many other objects like mouse, key, wallet,hand etc.)
can you help me fixing this problem
I took images of phone through camera using burst mode. captured positive images through different angles and different rotations
Negative images are taken from internet.

what should I do to increase cascade accuracy??

should I change size of positive or negative images?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming question. Maybe try Cross Validated?

Comment: Increasing number if samples and number of stages are the only ways to increase accuracy, But it will definitely take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very much a novice but found this article helpful:

https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/

In it the author mentions a rule of thumb of using twice as many positives as negatives. He also discusses a method for generating the positive images by overlaying the positive image(s) over the negative images using `opencv_createsamples` (which also rotates the positive image for you).

He is also scaling the negatives and converting them to grayscale prior to positive image sample generation and training.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to squeeze your criteria a bit while training your haar cascade:

```
-miniHitRate
-maxFalseAlarmRate
```

are set to 1 by default, squeeze them to 0.5 or even further down to get a more accurate cascade.
try:

```
opencv_traincascade -data data -vec crop1.vec -bg mob_neg.txt -numPos 850 -numNeg 900 -numStages 15 -miniHitRate 0.5 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -w 50 -h 50 bgcolor 255 -bgthresh 100
```